# MCP40821 DAC not responding to AVR

Tags: avr, c, spi, dac

I'm trying to interface with an MCP40821 using SPI from an AVR. Using these pin maps:

```
#define SCK     PB7
#define MOSI    PB5
#define CS      PB4
#define LDAC    PC7
```

With these register settings:

```
void SetupSPI()
{
    DDRB  |= true << SCK | true << MOSI | true << CS;
    DDRC  |= true << LDAC;
    PORTC |= true << LDAC;
    PORTB |= true << CS;
    SPCR  |= true << SPIE | true << SPE | true << MSTR | true << CPOL | true << CPHA;
    SPSR  |= true << SPI2X;
}
```

I'm then transmitting the data using a buffer and an interrupt.

```
#define SHDN    12
void SendSPIData()
{
    if (SPIBytesTransferred < SPIPayloadBytes)
    {
        SPDR = SPITxBuffer[SPIBytesTransferred++];
    }
    else
    {
        DACReady = true;
    }
}

void SetDAC(uint16_t value)
{
    if (!DACReady) return;
    DACReady = false;
    value |= true << SHDN;

    SPIPayloadBytes = DAC_SPI_BYTES;
    SPIBytesTransferred = 0;
    SPITxBuffer[0] = value >> 8;
    SPITxBuffer[1] = value;

    SendSPIData(); //Kick-off transfer
}

ISR(SPI_STC_vect)
{
    SendSPIData(); //Send next byte
}
```

This all seems to look fine, using my logic analyser I can see the two byte commands go out successfully.

However, the DAC doesn't seem to respond and I'm not sure what else I need to do.

[image: Logic Analyser]

Comment: Your chip select is always low... some chips (I haven't checked this one) require an explicit down-going edge on their chip select. I would check that first.

Comment: What response were you expecting? And do you need to pulse LDAC according to the (should be linked in the question) datasheet?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I was expecting the DAC value to change, no response back. Will give pulsing LDAC and CS a try tomorrow, thanks

Comment: What's a "MCP40821"? The only hit I get on Google is this very post. MCP4821? MCP4801?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the image below.  You need to pulse LDAC and CS needs a falling edge as was stated in the comments.

[image]

Comment: That sorted it, I thought LDAC was being handled by the peripheral